# pointer to abstract base class need some cast? C++

Tags: c++, pointers, casting

I have 2 classes:

```
class MyAbstractClass
{
public:
 virtual const std::string& getStr() const =0;
}

class MyRealClass : public MyAbstractClass
{
public: 
virtual const std::string& getStr() const { return m_str;};

private:
std::string m_str;
}
```

I have in main:

```
MyAbstractClass* ptr = new(MyRealClass("some string"));
```

I want to get the string information stored in `MyRealClass` **via a pointer to a base class**. 
Do I need to cast somehow `ptr` to `MyRealClass` to get info? or the run-time environment will be just smart enough to figure out that I am actually calling `getStr` from  `MyRealClass` ?

`ptr->getStr();` 
or something else like `static_cast<MyRealClass*>(ptr)->getStr();` or even `dynamic_cast<MyRealClass*>(ptr)->getStr();` ?

**In general, do we actually need to cast if we are using a pointer to a Abstract base class, not just to a simple (real) base class ?**

Comment: Have you tried any of those alternatives? Did any work? Did any fail?

Comment: Please compile your code before asking !

Comment: Note that you can remove half of the parentheses in the `new` statement and it will still mean the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is something called **Polymorphism**, it is a feature of object oriented programming languages (such as C++).

To make a method polymorphic you have to tag it as virtual (like you did with getStr() in your example), as long as your methods are virtual you can override them in a derived class, and if you call those method from a base class pointer it will call the version of the class you instantiated (MyRealClass in your example). If you do not tag them as virtual, they will call the version of the method from the type of the pointer you have. (if you wanna know more about the subject, search for "Virtual table", "virtual dispatch" and "late binding")

Note that when you write:

```
virtual void someMethod() = 0;
```

You are declaring what is known as pure virtual method, since they dont have their own implementation, you are forced to define them in the derived classes (thats how interfaces and abstract classes are made in C++).

Answer (score 0):

To cast from derived class to base class, you can use `static_cast`, although the compiler is smart enough to do it on it's own (without the need to actually do the cast). So this is enough :

```
MyAbstractClass* ptr = new(MyRealClass("some string"));
```

However, in your case, your base class has no virtual destructor, and what you get when deleting is an undefined behavior.

---

If you want to cast from base to derived - static_cast is not enough. Then you need to use dynamic_cast, and check if it succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

No; you can call members of pointers to children of abstract base classes through abstract classes. Although the code example you showed is incomplete.

Adding a virtual destructor to the interface, and a constructor for the concrete class, as well as cleaning some semi-colons - we get:

```
#include<string>

class MyAbstractClass{
public:
  virtual const std::string& getStr() const = 0;

  virtual ~MyAbstractClass(){}
};

class MyRealClass : public MyAbstractClass{
public:
  MyRealClass(std::string str) :
    m_str(str)
  {}

  virtual const std::string& getStr() const{ 
    return m_str;
  }
private:
  std::string m_str;
};
```

Now, the call `MyAbstractClass* ptr = new MyRealClass("some string");` will let `ptr->getStr()` return "some string".